# Transformar e devolver uma string s centralizada em uma string de comprimento width

Tags: c, string, funções

Neste exercício devo passar para a função uma string, um tamanho e o caracter que desejo incluir na string, porem encontro problemas ao executa-lo, a string que deveria ficar centralizada acaba sendo preenchida pelos asteristicos.

```
//Como deveria ficar:  asteristicos Apresentando os dados asteristicos 

/*Transforma e devolve a string s centralizada em uma string
de comprimento width. O preenchimento é feito usando o
caractere especificado por fillchar. A string original
é devolvida se width for menor ou igual a strlen(s).*/

char * redefine(char * s, int width, char fillchar){
    int i;
    char aux;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 46 ; i++){
        aux = s[i];
        s[i] = fillchar;
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", s); //Teste para ver ser a string esta correta.
}   

int main(){
    char str2[81] = "Apresentando os dados";

    // forma usada como teste.
    redefine(str2, 80, '*')
    // assim é a chamada da função printf("\"%s\"\n", redefine(str2, 80, '*'));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa calcular quantas posições tem que preencher. Preencha metade copie a string e preencha as posições restantes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char * redefine(char * s, int width, char fillchar){
    int i, n;
    char aux[width];
    if (strlen(s) >= width)
        return s;
    n = (width - strlen(s)) / 2;
    for(i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        aux[i] = fillchar;
    }
    aux[i] = '\0';
    strcat(aux, s);
    for (i=strlen(aux); i<width-1; i++) {
        aux[i] = fillchar;
    }
    aux[width-1] = '\0';
    strcpy(s, aux);
    return s;
}   

int main(){
    char str2[81] = "Apresentando os dados";
    printf("\n[%s]\n", redefine(str2, 80, '*'));

    return 0;
}
```